# Visual Studio 2017: The command "gulp" exited with code 9009

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-2017, gulp, visual-studio-2017-build-tools

Net App and my issue is when I hit `Rebuild` it throws an error: `Visual Studio 2017: The command "gulp" exited with code 9009`

Full log you can see [here][1]

**The short story:**

Everything worked fine until yesterday, where I was updating python from 2.x to python3.

After that my global variable $(PATH) became instead of `C:\Program Files\nodejs` => `C:\python39\`

I edited `$(PATH)` and put it again `C:\Program Files\nodejs` into my external tools:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qlyIi.png
I also add as second location of external tools my `%AppData%` folder for npm as you can see on the image above. I checked that folder and there is a gulp cmd file. So it should be recognizable.

However when I hit rebuild, I still have this error as I shown from my logs.

This is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "testtest",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "css": "gulp"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "5.9.1",
    "npm": "3.7.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.0",
    "gulp-htmlclean": "^2.7.22",
    "gulp-less": "^3.1.0",
    "gulp-minify-css": "^1.2.4",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^2.3.0",
    "gulp-uglify": "^2.1.2",
    "gulp-util": "^3.0.7",
    "merge-stream": "^1.0.0"
  }
}
```

This is mine setup of `npm version` from cli:

```
{
  gulp: '3.9.1',
  npm: '6.14.6',
  ares: '1.16.0',
  brotli: '1.0.7',
  cldr: '37.0',
  http_parser: '2.9.3',
  icu: '67.1',
  llhttp: '2.1.2',
  modules: '72',
  napi: '6',
  nghttp2: '1.41.0',
  node: '12.18.4',
  openssl: '1.1.1g',
  tz: '2019c',
  unicode: '13.0',
  uv: '1.38.0',
  v8: '7.8.279.23-node.39',
  zlib: '1.2.11'
}
```

I tried different versions of nodejs (12.x.x and 10.x.x) I have same behavior.
[1]: https://pastebin.com/4srU2yB0